# What is the best practice in handling weird exceptions in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

let's say that I have this function in Rails (I have actually :P - eval is used because there will be third, fourth or more as class_number in the future) :

```
    def all_profession_costs(class_number)
        second = {'Wealth Ranger' => 1000, 'Wisdom Vacuum' => 1000, 'Life Leecher' => 1000, 'Dense Mass' => 1000}
        costs = eval(class_number)
        costs
    end
```

This seems to be working fine now, but if I accidentally use 'firsta' for my class_number, the whole thing will likely collapse and maybe there will be a difficult error to spot.

So, now I'm thinking two things. I definitely want to check things as much as possible, but I don't like putting things like "raise RuntimeError", because it makes the code much uglier. And makes it run slower. Well, I suppose the latter is bearable, since checking means better code.

However, I don't like ugly. I'm thinking of creating a separate ExceptionHandling module, in order to do validation stuff like that.

In this example, I would want to check whether class_number is 'first', 'second' or 'third'.

Instead of something like:

```
raise RuntimeError unless ['first', 'second', 'third'].include?(class_number.to_s)
```

Maybe I could write a simple module (working probably like a Python decorator), that will make this thing better to read, what I think is more beautiful code, something like:

```
validates class_number, :inclusion => ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

Sort of like the standard model validator.

What do you think about that? Is that a good idea or not? How would you treat some error handling in Rails?

Comment: it's just a function parameter picking the first, second or third hash (in this example only second hash exists in the function, but more will be added). Don't worry about that at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Validation** - In the example given by you, you don't **have** to raise an exception. You could simply return false if class_number is not either one of "first", "second", "third". And check the response where the method gets called. This approach is the validation approach.

**Exception** - You raise exceptions when the error that may be cause is not due to bad user input but because something seriously went wrong in your logic, implementation or factors you don't have control over.

These are not hard and fast rules though. They are more of a guideline that I usually follow.

In the above example, it depends on where the `class_number` is coming from. Is it coming from a user input? I would do a validation. If it is not supposed to come from a user input, I would raise an exception. Also, you don't have to simple raise a `RuntimeError`. You can design your own exception class. In your case, something like,

```
class InvalidClassNumber < RuntimeError
end
```

and do
    unless ['first', 'second', 'third'].include?(class_number.to_s)
      raise InvalidClassNumber, "Class number can either be 'first', 'second' or 'third'. We got #{class_number.to_s}"
    end

Where you call this method, you can rescue it and do whatever you need to do handle it.

```
begin
  @profession = @user.profession(class_number)
rescue InvalidClassNumber => e
  # Do whatever you need to
  logger.debug e.message
  # redirect somewhere, or whatever
end
```

Custom exception classes give you the flexibility to handle precisely those exceptions that you are expecting, instead of handling a generic exception like `RuntimeError`. You can have as many exception classes as you need in your application. You can even give them a namespace using `::`. `Profession::InvalidClassNumber < RuntimeError`.

Comment: Hello Chirantan and thanx for the very informative reply. I still find the begin rescue end handling quite ugly to say the truth. What would you think about a validation the way i describe it in my question ? (bear in mind that class_name comes from me, the programmer, in this case). Maybe i could go as far as having a different case of validation for user input and programmer input. Do you think that would be a good idea ?

Comment: Exception handling is still pretty clean to me and probably the most sensible way of error message passing through the program. If we go your route, how would pass the validation message back to the place from where it was called? You would probably have to follow the active record model of validation. I would still recommend the exceptions for this kind of a case. I usually try to avoid them whenever possible but yours looks like a typical case for exception handling.

Comment: I was actually thinking of using the "validates" idea that i mention above, implemented with exceptions. So, 'validates :class_number on inclusion', would actually raise an exception if not included. This way, all the background stuff, like messages and further handling would happen inside the module.